# Is it possible to wrap the word in UITableViewSectionIndex?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to wrap the word in section index displaying on the right side of the UItableView.

The problem is that, if the word length increases the section index width also increases and table view cell content view size reduces.And I do not want to display substring of section index array object.Since I want to display whole word in the section i have to wrap it.

```
-(NSArray*) sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i <[keys count]; i++) {
        NSString *str = [self.keys objectAtIndex:i];
           [array addObject:str];
    }

    NSArray *a =[NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
    [array release];
    return a;
}
```

object in the array return by sectionIndextitle method is lengthy and I want to wrap the word.

Any one knows how it can be done?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code to for better idea of problem.

Comment: Does a section index even allow multi-line titles? I doubt it. But you could check that out by assigning something like `@"One\nTwo"` to `str` and see what happens. If it works, you could write your own method to break the title strings so that they fit in a given width. (Since table titles accept only plain-vanilla NSStrings, it's unlikely that there is any autowrapping mechanism available.)

Comment: I have already checked that using \n it will work on webpage not in section index

Comment: Just check the 'str' before adding it in array, is it having one or more word and select the range how much you want and add it in your array..

Comment: It sounds to me that you are misusing this method. This is not designed to be like a book index that gives full words, it is simply a "jump" to an easily identifiable area of your table. What is your ultimate goal for this? From a UI standpoint, I can't see what you are describing looking good.

Answer (score 2):

you can only create your own "section index view" as a custom UIView

and it's eazy to do that

just calc the height of your tableview , calc the count of your sections

then draw your section title on it in

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

then detect the touch event

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

calc which section you touched , then call the tableview method

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

then  put it on your tableview, eazy done!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your answer is no but the following should solve the problem behind your question.

I would use this function instead tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: on the UITableViewDelegate protocol.  More information can be found in the documentation here [UITableViewDelegate Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  Note – tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: must also be implemented.  This combination of functions will allow you to return a view with a UILabel subview that has numberOfLines set to 0, i.e. as many as necessary, and the text set to whatever value you need.

Comment: I don't understand your way to use the combination of functions.Please explain it...

Comment: @Dave, that is not what he is asking. He is asking for the section index on the right side, not the header views. I doubt there is a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to wrap section indexes to multiple lines. This wouldn't make sense in the default UI. A custom header is your best bet to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom title header for section. There you can use the label and assign the number of lines into it on the basis of length of the title. You will also need to set height of section header accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the '`str`' before adding it in `NSMutableArray`, is it having one or more word?
 and select the range how much you want and add it in your array..

USe `NSmakeRange` to make the range of characters, that you want to show in index of the each section..

Comment: Sorry but I do not want to show the truncated words , I want to wrap the word in section index if its length exceeds the sectionIndex Width

Comment: then write a logic to wrap the word as yourself

Comment: check the position of "spaces" from your text and get the sectionindex width. and if the space match between -5 or +5 to the sectionIndex width then wrap the word to next place..

Comment: If I will wrap the word to next place then, how it will search in table view when we scroll it because at next place it gets new word not the word matching with section title

Comment: add that into NSmutableArray and then add nsmutablearray items to your nsarray

Comment: but SectionForTitle index returns array of NSStrings not an array of NSMutableArray..It doesn't allow me to return array of NSMutableArray where I can upload screen shot

Comment: I didn't mean you to return array of nsmutablearray.you understood wrongly.i just said you to copy the items to nsarray.Could you just post your screenshot what you are getting??

Comment: I have edited the question by uploading image u can see above , In this image on the RHS of tableview i just want to display two lines of wrapped word(AS numberoflines=2 in tableviewcell).

Comment: have u get my message on chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11106/discussion-between-prince-kumar-and-r-a